# Getting error when building dev node

Tags: substrate-node

I've tried following the instructions and double checking evrything at each stage but I still end up with the following error... Any ideas please?

```rs
error[E0282]: type annotations needed
    --> /Users/richard/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/sp-arithmetic-2.0.0/src/fixed_point.rs:541:9
     |
541  |                   let accuracy = P::ACCURACY.saturated_into();
     |                       ^^^^^^^^
...
1614 | / implement_fixed!(
1615 | |     FixedU128,
1616 | |     test_fixed_u128,
1617 | |     u128,
...    |
1621 | |         [0.000000000000000000, 340282366920938463463.374607431768211455]_",
1622 | | );
     | |_- in this macro invocation
     |
     = note: this error originates in the macro `implement_fixed` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)
help: consider giving `accuracy` an explicit type
     |
541  |                 let accuracy: _ = P::ACCURACY.saturated_into();
     |                             +++

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0282`.
error: could not compile `sp-arithmetic` due to 3 previous errors
warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
richard@richardimac substrate-node-template %
```

Answer (score 1):

sp-arithmetic-2.0 is a pretty old version. It was released two years ago.

So, downgrade your rust toolchain version or upgrade the sp-arithmetic version.

Comment: So sorry for the delay.... thank you so much for your help.. got it sorted :)

Comment: If this helps you, please mark this as the answer.

Comment: I actually needed to load protoc then it seemed fine

Answer (score 0):

I actually needed to load protoc then it seemed fine... https://grpc.io/docs/protoc-installation/